# Mountain Lion won't wake up after an extended sleep

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I've recently upgraded my MacBook Air to Mountain Lion. Now whenever the machine sleeps for a long time (more than two hours or so) while disconnected from the mains, it won't wake up.  I had to hold the power button to reboot the machine.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Related questions: [Macbook Air (13" 2012) Fails to wake from sleep](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39428), [Mid 2010 MacBook Pro Won't Wake Up](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46966/mid-2010-macbook-pro-wont-wake-up?rq=1), [New MacBook Pro won't wake from sleep without restart](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12316/new-macbook-pro-wont-wake-from-sleep-without-restart?rq=1). Have you tried resetting [NVRAM and PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) or disabling [standby mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392) with `sudo pmset -a standby 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that hasn't been fixed as of 10.8.1. When Mountain Lion [hibernates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_%28computing%29#Mac_OS_X) (either directly or as part of [standby mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392)), it couldn't wake up and thus need to be restarted.

The current workarounds are:

- Disable hibernate mode.
- Disable standby mode.

I've written an [article how to get around this issue by preventing OS X from hibernating](http://basilsalad.com/how-to/mountain-lion-wake-issue/).

For Apple folks: *please see `rdar://1212084` - Thanks*.

Comment: Apple still hasn't fix this in 10.8.2.

Comment: or 10.8.4, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, maybe you can try the following ways to wake up your Mac.

Hold the power button for two seconds, then release the button, not until reboot. 
If this way does not work, try this:
Adjust the light button F2, maybe just the screen does not light.

Good luck!